# Phrase for one idea causing another

Tags: phrases, expressions

I'm looking for an elegant phrase describing why group brainstorms are effective.

At the moment I have "allows one person to spark ideas in another".

It doesn't seem right, what's a better verb or phrase?

Thanks

Comment: "Cascade of ideas"

Comment: Maybe “to inspire each other“ works.

Comment: Each new idea in a brainstorming session potentially _triggers_ fresh ideas from other participants.

Answer (score 1):

[stimulate from OxfordLiving Dictionaries site](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stimulate)

> ***stimulate***
>   VERB [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1Raise levels of physiological or nervous activity in (the body or any biological system)
>
> *‘the women are given fertility drugs to stimulate their ovaries’*
>
> 1.1 Encourage or arouse interest or enthusiasm in.
>
> *the reader could not fail to be stimulated by the ideas presented*
>
> 1.2 Encourage development of or increased activity in (a state or process)
>
> *‘the courses stimulate a passion for learning’*

I think the reason why "sparking one's interest" works is because it stimulates the mind as applied to a topic as described above

Comment: Tom, you don't have to quote the whole definition.  You can include just the relevant parts in your answer.